# Homework on matrix and convex set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization

> Suppose that $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and both symmetric. Define
>   $$
> H=\{\sigma\in\mathbb{R} \mid A+\sigma B \text{ is semi-positive definite}\}
> $$ 
>   Assume that there exist $\sigma_1\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $A+\sigma_1B$ is positive definite, $a=\inf_{x\in H} x$, $b=\sup_{x\in H} x$. Prove that $a<b$, and for any $\sigma\in(a,b)$, $A+\sigma B$ is positive definite.

Comment: This looks like an exercise with no context. What have you tried to prove this? Where did the problem come from?

Comment: @MikePierce, well. I am studying on a course named "linear conic programming". This exercise comes from this course.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the eigenvalues of a matrix depend continuously on its entries.  So, if there exist a $\sigma_1$ such that the smallest eigenvalue $A + \sigma_1 B$ is positive, then there exists an $\delta > 0$ such that the lowest eigenvalue $A + \sigma B$ is positive for any real $\sigma$ with $|\sigma - \sigma_1| < \delta$.

This is enough to show that $a < b$.

We may then show that $H$ is a convex set by noting that
$$
A + (s\sigma_1 + t\sigma_2)B = s(A + \sigma_1B) + t(A + s \sigma_2B)
$$
for any $s,t \geq 0$ satisfying $s + t = 1$.

---

If we wanted to avoid continuous dependence of eigenvalues on entries, then it suffices to note that
$$
\sigma \mapsto \min_{\|x\| = 1} x^*(A + \sigma B)x
$$
is a continous function.  This is a straightforward analytic proof.

---

**Showing that if $\sigma \in (a,b)$, then $A + \sigma B$ is positive *definite*:**

Suppose that there exists a $\sigma_0 \in (a,b)$ such that $A + \sigma_0 B$ is non-invertible.  Then $A+aB,A+\sigma_0B,A+bB$ are three co-linear points that lie on the boundary of the set of positive semidefinite matrices.

Since $A+aB,A+\sigma_0B,A+bB$ are distinct co-linear points on the border of a convex set, we may deduce that all points on the line segment from $A + aB$ to $A + bB$ lie on the border.  That is, $A + \sigma B$ is positive semidefinite for every $\sigma \in (a,b)$.  This, however, contradicts the assumption that $A + \sigma_1 B $ is positive definite.

Comment: By showing that $H$ is convex, we can only proof that for any $\sigma\in(a,b)$, $A+\sigma B$ is semi-positive definite? How to prove it is positive-definite?

Comment: I missed that detail in the question.  I will think about it.

Comment: See my latest edit